# Vue.jsで{{○○}}がそのまま出力されてしまう

Tags: vue.js

Vue.jsの学習を始めた超初心者です。
参考書を片手に理解しようとしているのですが、
参考書に掲載されているソースコードを書いても正しい出力結果が表示されません。

具体的には

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="sample">
    ただいまの時間は{{time}}です。
  </div>
</body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    Vue.createApp({
      el: '#sample',
      data: {
        time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
      }
    })
  </script>
</html>
```

参考書によれば、このようにコードを書けば、出力結果は

> ただいまの時間はH:mm:ssです。

となるようなのですが、実際の出力内容は

> ただいまの時間は{{time}}です。

と波かっこがそのまま表示されてしまいます。
なぜなのでしょうか。参考書に掲載されているコードが間違っているのでしょうか？

わかる方は教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 「参考書に掲載されているソースコード」を正しく入力されていないのでは？ 例えば`</body>`がHTMLソースの途中にありますが、それは最終行の`</html>`の直前に記述されるものでは？[Vue.js 現在時刻の表示 ~時計~](https://qiita.com/ron-Qiita/items/17af311a506d08b7bf14), [Vue.jsを使ってデジタル時計を作る方法を解説](https://naoya-ono.com/blog/vue-clock/), [初心者向け。Vue.jsのデジタル時計アプリの作り方を詳しく解説](https://newsite-make.com/vue-clock/)  それから書籍の内容を基にしているなら、書籍の名称や掲載ページ等の情報を記述してください。他にもこちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。参考書籍は『Vue.js』ポケットリファレンス（技術評論社：2023年5月2日 初版）。「3.3 HTMLに直接Vue.jsを組み込む」のページを参照しました。
スペルミスがないことは何度も確認しましたがダメでした。
また、</body>と</html>の間に<script>が入っているのも参考書籍掲載のコードの通りです。

Comment: 約2ヵ月前に出たばかり [Vue.jsポケットリファレンス](https://gihyo.jp/book/2023/978-4-297-13479-2) のようなので、そのうちサポートページとか正誤情報とかの追記が出るのでは？ 貴方自身で出版社に問い合わせてみても良いと思われます。

Comment: 深追いして調べてみました。本書は「Vue.js3対応」と謳っているにも関わらず、今回取り上げたサンプルコードはVue.js 2系では正常に処理されるけど、3に対応していないものでした。

「Vue.js3対応」と謳われているので、当然サンプルコードもVue.js3に対応しているものと思っていましたが、そうではなかったみたいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScriptコードの部分を次のようにしてください。

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      time: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
    };
  }
}).mount('#sample');
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
記載していただいたコードに変えたところ、意図通りの出力となりました。  
やはり参考にした書籍のコードが間違っていたのでしょうか.....
2023年5月刊と新しめの書籍なので、問題ないだろうと思っていたのですが。

Comment: Vue2 → Vue3の変更で、elパラメータではDOMにマウントできなくなっていていました。参考にした書籍が「Vue.js3対応」と書かれていたので、掲載されているサンプルコードも3に対応していると思っていましたが、Vue.js2用のコードでした。それがわからず、CDNでVue.js3を読み込んでいたせいで意図した結果にならなかった、というのが原因でした。